# Prevent Mobile Navbar from Covering the Webpage when Anchor Link is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, navbar

So far, I've been able to get everything else to work so far in regards to the responsive navigation bar on my website, which is a streamlined single page. While every other component is functional, the main issue is on the mobile version, where the navigation bar doesn't close when an anchor link is clicked. It ends up covering content and creates a bad experience for the user. How would this be fixed in the code? The code is below:

```
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <label>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"/>
    </a>
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



/* NAVBAR */
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

nav{
  background: white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a{
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.active,a:hover{
  background: #B9ECFF;
  transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px){
  label.logo{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }

  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 858px){
  .checkbtn{
    display: block;
  }

  ul{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: white;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }

  nav ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  a:hover,a.active{
    background: none;
    color: #25C0F8;
  }

  #check:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the situation is:
you click on navbar -> navbar opens -> click on a nav menu -> navbar doesn't close while loading other page/ going #point

Here is the solution for that situation:
you click on navbar -> navbar opens -> click on a nav menu -> (perform another click on navbar)
cause, clicking navbar opens and closes the navbar..right?

follow these steps:

1.put a `id` on nav that show and hide nav menus
suppose that is "`mainnavbar`"

```
<nav id="mainnavbar">
```

2.add `onclick` attribute to every anchor tag and `hidenavvar()` as its value:

```
<a onclick="hidenavbar()">
```

3.declare `hidenavbar()` function in js:

```
<script>
function hidenavbar()
{
    document.getElementById('mainnavbar').click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, the problem still persists.

Comment: you need to see what is showing and hiding nav menus.
maybe its not the <nav> tag

Comment: I tried this on mutliple tags but same outcome.

Comment: Currently looking up mobile responsive navbars and it says that there's this toggle function in JS. Would this be relevant in any way?

Comment: toggle function used in jQuery.
I wish i could see your full code!!

Comment: might create a separate file just to test out the toggle function!